# Google App Engine Jinja2 template extends base template from parent folder

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2

I am using Google App Engine with Python/Jinja2

I have a few html content files, like content1.html, content2.html and content3.html. Each of them need to extend a base html file called base.html.

Suppose these 4 files are in the some folder, then at the beginning of the content files, I just need to put {% extends "base.html" %}, and the html files render well.

However, as my project grows, more and more pages have been created. I would like to organize the files by creating sub-folders. So now suppose in the root directory, I have the base.html and subfolder1. Inside subfolder1, I have content1.html.

In my python:

```
JINJA_ENVIRONMENT = jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))+"\\subfolder1"))
template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template("content1.html")
template.render({})
```

or

```
JINJA_ENVIRONMENT = jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))))
template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template("subfolder1\\content1.html")
template.render({})
```

But then in content1.html,

```
{% extends "????????" %}
```

what should put in the question marks to extend the base.html which is in the parent folder?

Answer (score 10):

more clearly:

```
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('templates'))
```

The folder `templates` is now the template's root:

```
template = env.get_template('content.html') # /templates/content.html
self.response.write(template.render())
```

or using subfolders:

```
template = env.get_template('folder/content.html')
self.response.write(template.render())
```

in content.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}        # /templates/base.html
{% extends "folder/base.html" %} # /templates/folder/base.html
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
JINJA_ENVIRONMENT = jinja2.Environment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(
        [os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)),
         os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)) + "/subfolder1"]))
```

then:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
```

according this:
http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#basics (class jinja2.FileSystemLoader(searchpath, encoding='utf-8'))